Question about a property of the integer-hull
If I have a convex set $Q\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a cone $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $Q_I =  conv\{Q \cap   \mathbb{Z}^n\}$ and $E_I$ respectively.
Is it in general the case that $Q_I + E_I \subseteq (Q+E)_I$ ?

You should try basic stuff first. Take $Q={{1 \over 2}}$ and $E = [0,\infty)$. Then $Q_I = \emptyset$ but $(Q+E)_I = \mathbb{N}$.

I think I'm missing the point of this comment. The empty set is a subset of every set, so $Q_I = \emptyset \implies Q_I + E_I = \emptyset \subset \mathbb{N}.$

Let $q\in Q_I$ and $e\in E_I.$ We can write them as $$q=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k}q_{k}$$ and $$e=\sum_{j=1}^{J}\mu_{j}e_{j}$$ where $q_{k}\in Q\cap\mathbb{Z}^{n},$ $e_{j}\in E\cap\mathbb{Z}^{n},$ $\lambda \ge 0,$ $\sum_{k}\lambda_{k}=1,$ $\mu \ge 0$ and $\sum_{j}\mu_{j}=1.$ Now we just do a bunch of algebra.
$$ \begin{align} q+e & =\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k}q_{k}+\sum_{j=1}^{J}\mu_{j}e_{j}\\\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k}q_{k}(\sum_{j=1}^{J}\mu_{j})+\sum_{j=1}^{J}\mu_{j}e_{j}(\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k})\\\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\lambda_{k}\mu_{j}(q_{k}+e_{j})\\\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\lambda_{k}\mu_{j}z_{kj}\end{align} $$
where $z_{kj}=q_{k}+e_{j}\in(Q+E)\cap\mathbb{Z}^{n}.$ Since the weights $\lambda_{k}\mu_{j}$ are nonnegative with $$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\lambda_{k}\mu_{j}=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k}(\sum_{j=1}^{J}\mu_{j})=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_{k}=1,$$ we have $q+e\in (Q+E)_I.$

I didn't think of multiplying the two series with a "1". Thank you!
